# Azure IoT hub auto reverting changes in device twin

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm observing a strange behaviour in my device's twin. I want to change a desired property with [example code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/master/iot-hub/Samples/service/RegistryManagerSample/RegistryManagerSample.cs#L135). It works as expected: desired value changes, device updates value and so the reported property also changes to my new value. But after a few minutes - without any apparent reason - both values are reverted to their original value. Is it some kind of iot hub funcionality (e.g. do I need to "commit" my changes somehow?) or is it a fault of device itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was my misunderstanding of how automatic config management works. I had my configuration added to "IoT device configuration" section which was overriding manual changes made to any device. So I solved it by deleting this config.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved. you can accept your solution as answer.